# How can I debug the following error in aTomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks

I am running a tomcat server and some where in one of the packages I'm using there seems to be some memory leak. I get the following error. Can someone tell me how I can debug an issue like this please. I am using IntelliJ IDE.

```
May 05, 2016 7:27:47 PM org.oceanbandit.solver.BanditSolver writeNewFeatureToDataBaseHybridModel
INFO: Update duration in LinUCB Hybrid27583650
May 05, 2016 7:27:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
May 05, 2016 7:27:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 05, 2016 7:27:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [sFeedbackServlet]
May 05, 2016 7:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [sFeedbackServlet]
May 05, 2016 7:27:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [sFeedbackServlet]
May 05, 2016 7:27:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
May 05, 2016 7:27:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tomcat is trying to unload the webapp but there is still a request running. You could attach intellij debugger to the tomcat process if it is stated with remote debugging options to see what that request is.

Comment: How can I attached the intellij debugger to the tomcat process

Comment: These two should help you
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-remote.html